# Django admin can't see all entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I follow Practical Django Project to write a blog. But the change list only displays entries with status LIVE. Although other entries with status DRAFT and HIDDEN are stored in database, they are not shown in change list . Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Flowing is model.py

```
class LiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
    return super(LiveManager,self).get_query_set().filter(status=self.model.LIVE_STATUS)

class Post(models.Model):

    LIVE_STATUS=1
    DRAFT_STATUS=2
    HIDDEN_STATUS=3
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
    (LIVE_STATUS,'Live'),
    (DRAFT_STATUS,'Draft'),
    (HIDDEN_STATUS,'Hidden')
    )

    status=models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    category=models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    content_markdown=models.TextField(blank=True)
    content_markup=models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
    live=LiveManager()
    objects=models.Manager()


    def save(self):
        self.content_markup=markdown(self.content_markdown,['codehilite'])
        super(Post,self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.title)
```

Here is admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=['content_markup']
    prepopulated_fields={'slug':('title',)}
    list_display=['title','status']

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields={'slug':('title',)}

admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

Comment: What's the question? Your `LiveManager` is filtering on `status=self.model.LIVE_STATUS` and will therefore not give you any other entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs:

"...the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager"

So just make sure `objects=models.Manager()` comes before `live=LiveManager()`

Comment: It works. Thank you every much. I have been staring at computer for so long.

Answer (score 0):

ModelAdmin use self.model._default_manager. So you can also override queryset method of PostAdmin:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        """
        Returns a QuerySet of all model instances that can be edited by the
        admin site. This is used by changelist_view.
        """
        qs = self.model.objects.get_query_set()

        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
       ...
```

Or you can set _default_manager = objects in Post model.